# Black beans instead of red beans for chili con carne?

Tags: substitutions, chili

I mistakenly bought a can of pre-cooked (I don't have time to soak and cook the beans from raw) black beans instead of red beans

Is that usable for chili (i.e would that be as good as the red beans recipe)? Would I need to adjust cooking time in order to have a good result?

Comment: Just FYI: classic "chili con carne", in the San Antonio Mexican sense, has no beans at all.  It's just meat, peppers, and sometimes tomatoes.  However, there's hundreds of recipes that confuse "American Chili" with "Chile Con Carne", so you can do whatever you want.  Just making a note as the resident food history geek.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you’re planning to just heat the beans through, you can probably just use the recipe as-is, as canned beans are already cooked.

If you are trying to cook the beans until they fall apart and mash them as a thickener, as black beans are smaller than standard red kidney beans, you typically need a little less time.

And yes, they work fine in chili.  When I’m making a vegetarian chili, I often use both types so there’s more variety of texture.